# EVM transaction gas fees not added to the treasury

Tags: transactions, evm, fee, pallet-treasury, frontier-node-template

I've implemented a POA EVM-Compatible chain using the Frontier node template on branch polkadot-v0.9.22.

I've Implemented a DealWithFees struct and let some part of fees be added to a treasury i've implemented. I'm running all the defaults which came with Frontier's node template having made no changes to pallet evm, ethereum, baseFee or dynamic_fee's configs.

Ive set pallet EVM's OnChargeTransaction to EVMCurrencyAdapter<Balances, DealWithFees>.

But after executing an EVM transaction, no change is observed in the treasury.

**NOTE** I have fixed the fee for every transaction at 250,000,000,000 balance.

```rust
pub struct ToAuthor<R>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<R>);
impl<R> OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance<R>> for ToAuthor<R>
where
    R: pallet_balances::Config + pallet_authorship::Config,
    <R as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: From<AccountId>,
    <R as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: Into<AccountId>,
    <R as frame_system::Config>::Event: From<pallet_balances::Event<R>>,
{
    fn on_nonzero_unbalanced(amount: NegativeImbalance<R>) {
        if let Some(author) = <pallet_authorship::Pallet<R>>::author() {
            <pallet_balances::Pallet<R>>::resolve_creating(&author, amount);
        }
    }
}

pub struct DealWithFees<R>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<R>);
impl<R> OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance<R>> for DealWithFees<R>
where
    R: pallet_balances::Config + pallet_treasury::Config + pallet_authorship::Config,
    pallet_treasury::Pallet<R>: OnUnbalanced<NegativeImbalance<R>>,
    <R as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: From<AccountId>,
    <R as frame_system::Config>::AccountId: Into<AccountId>,
    <R as frame_system::Config>::Event: From<pallet_balances::Event<R>>,
{
    fn on_unbalanceds<B>(mut fees_then_tips: impl Iterator<Item = NegativeImbalance<R>>) {
        if let Some(fees) = fees_then_tips.next() {
            // for fees, 75% to treasury, 25% to author
            let mut split = fees.ration(75, 25);
            if let Some(tips) = fees_then_tips.next() {
                // for tips, if any, 100% to author
                tips.merge_into(&mut split.1);
            }
            use pallet_treasury::Pallet as Treasury;
            <Treasury<R> as OnUnbalanced<_>>::on_unbalanced(split.0);
            <ToAuthor<R> as OnUnbalanced<_>>::on_unbalanced(split.1);
        }
    }
}

const NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO: Perbill = Perbill::from_percent(75);
/// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block time.
pub const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT: Weight = 2 * WEIGHT_PER_SECOND;
const WEIGHT_PER_GAS: u64 = 20_000;

pub struct ConstantFee<T>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
impl<T> WeightToFeePolynomial for ConstantFee<T>
where
    T: BaseArithmetic + From<u32> + Copy + Unsigned + From<u64>,
{
    type Balance = T;

    fn polynomial() -> WeightToFeeCoefficients<Self::Balance> {
        let fee: u64 = (DOLLARS * 25).try_into().unwrap();
        smallvec!(WeightToFeeCoefficient {
            coeff_integer: fee.into(),
            coeff_frac: Perbill::zero(),
            negative: false,
            degree: 0,
        })
    }

    fn calc(_weight: &Weight) -> Self::Balance {
        let fee: u64 = (DOLLARS * 25).try_into().unwrap();
        return fee.into();
    }
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const TransactionByteFee: Balance = 1;
}

impl pallet_transaction_payment::Config for Runtime {
    type OnChargeTransaction = CurrencyAdapter<Balances, DealWithFees<Runtime>>;
    type OperationalFeeMultiplier = ConstU8<5>;
    type WeightToFee = ConstantFee<Balance>;
    type LengthToFee = ConstantMultiplier<Balance, TransactionByteFee>;
    
parameter_types! {
    pub const SpendPeriod: BlockNumber = 6 * DAYS;
    pub const TreasuryPalletId: PalletId = PalletId(*b"py/trsry");
    /// 5% of proposal value should be reserved from proposer balance,
    /// but not less than ProposalBondMinimum.
    /// This value would be slashed if proposal rejected.
    pub const ProposalBond: Permill = Permill::from_percent(0);
}

impl pallet_treasury::Config for Runtime {
    type Currency = Balances;
    // Only root for now, governance later.
    type ApproveOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
    // Only root for now, governance later.
    type RejectOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;

    type Event = Event;
    // If proposal rejected - send deposit to treasury.
    type OnSlash = Treasury;
    type ProposalBond = ProposalBond;
    type ProposalBondMinimum = ();
    type ProposalBondMaximum = ();
    type SpendPeriod = SpendPeriod;
    // Not burning.
    type Burn = ();
    type PalletId = TreasuryPalletId;
    type BurnDestination = ();
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type SpendFunds = ();
    type MaxApprovals = ConstU32<100>;
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const UncleGenerations: BlockNumber = 5;
}

impl pallet_authorship::Config for Runtime {
    type FindAuthor = pallet_session::FindAccountFromAuthorIndex<Self, Aura>;
    type UncleGenerations = UncleGenerations;
    type FilterUncle = ();
    type EventHandler = ();
}
pub struct FindAuthorTruncated<F>(PhantomData<F>);
impl<F: FindAuthor<u32>> FindAuthor<H160> for FindAuthorTruncated<F> {
    fn find_author<'a, I>(digests: I) -> Option<H160>
    where
        I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item = (ConsensusEngineId, &'a [u8])>,
    {
        if let Some(author_index) = F::find_author(digests) {
            let authority_id = Aura::authorities()[author_index as usize].clone();
            return Some(H160::from_slice(&authority_id.to_raw_vec()[4..24]));
        }
        None
    }
}

pub struct FixedGasWeightMapping;
impl GasWeightMapping for FixedGasWeightMapping {
    fn gas_to_weight(gas: u64) -> Weight {
        gas.saturating_mul(WEIGHT_PER_GAS)
    }
    fn weight_to_gas(weight: Weight) -> u64 {
        weight.wrapping_div(WEIGHT_PER_GAS)
    }
}

parameter_types! {
    pub const ChainId: u64 = 421;
    pub BlockGasLimit: U256 = U256::from(NORMAL_DISPATCH_RATIO * MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT / WEIGHT_PER_GAS);
    pub PrecompilesValue: FrontierPrecompiles<Runtime> = FrontierPrecompiles::<_>::new();
}

impl pallet_evm::Config for Runtime {
    type FeeCalculator = BaseFee;
    type GasWeightMapping = FixedGasWeightMapping;
    type BlockHashMapping = pallet_ethereum::EthereumBlockHashMapping<Self>;
    type CallOrigin = EnsureAddressTruncated;
    type WithdrawOrigin = EnsureAddressTruncated;
    type AddressMapping = HashedAddressMapping<BlakeTwo256>;
    type Currency = Balances;
    type Event = Event;
    type Runner = pallet_evm::runner::stack::Runner<Self>;
    type PrecompilesType = FrontierPrecompiles<Self>;
    type PrecompilesValue = PrecompilesValue;
    type ChainId = ChainId;
    type BlockGasLimit = BlockGasLimit;
    type OnChargeTransaction = EVMCurrencyAdapter<Balances, DealWithFees<Runtime>>;
    type FindAuthor = FindAuthorTruncated<Aura>;
}

impl pallet_ethereum::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type StateRoot = pallet_ethereum::IntermediateStateRoot<Self>;
}

frame_support::parameter_types! {
    pub BoundDivision: U256 = U256::from(1024);
}

impl pallet_dynamic_fee::Config for Runtime {
    type MinGasPriceBoundDivisor = BoundDivision;
}

frame_support::parameter_types! {
    pub IsActive: bool = false;
    pub DefaultBaseFeePerGas: U256 = U256::from(1_000_000_000);
}

pub struct BaseFeeThreshold;
impl pallet_base_fee::BaseFeeThreshold for BaseFeeThreshold {
    fn lower() -> Permill {
        Permill::zero()
    }
    fn ideal() -> Permill {
        Permill::from_parts(500_000)
    }
    fn upper() -> Permill {
        Permill::from_parts(1_000_000)
    }
}

impl pallet_base_fee::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Threshold = BaseFeeThreshold;
    type IsActive = IsActive;
    type DefaultBaseFeePerGas = DefaultBaseFeePerGas;
}

impl pallet_hotfix_sufficients::Config for Runtime {
    type AddressMapping = HashedAddressMapping<BlakeTwo256>;
    type WeightInfo = ();
}
```

Comment: Did you solved the issue ?

Comment: Yes, we were not implementing a method in DealWithFees struct, which led to runtime using a default implementation that was empty, hence not having the desired affect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to implement this for DealWithFees as well

```
fn on_nonzero_unbalanced(amount: NegativeImbalance<R>) {}
```